# reading date feature in csv file with python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new in the data analysis area. I'm trying to plot some features based on the date feature. the problem is the date column is not consistent, some are as yyyy, some as dd.mm.yyyy and some mm.yyyy.
something like this:

```
2.5.2020
2006
3.2012
```

so as I run my code :

```
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['date'].notna()].sort_values('date')
dataframe.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Student_ID')['Freq'].plot(legend=True)
```

I face:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'.
```

Would you please tell me how I can deal with this inconsistent date feature?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: You need to first reformat the date so that all the format are the same, and adequate to your usage. In order to do that, you may want to filter the data and apply an operation on it, as many times as needed so that all your dates are uniform. Only then will you be able to correctly plot your data